# Alguien sabe porque React me compila con error desde mi disco "D" pero si lo creo en el dico "C" lo ejecuta bien

Tags: reactjs, consola

Esta es la leyenda que me figura desde la consola
[image: Esta es la leyenda que me figura desde la consola]

Y esa es la leyenda ya una vez compilado
[image: Y esa es la leyenda ya una vez compilado]

¿Cómo hacer o que comando ejecutar desde la consola para que react me funciones desde el disco "D"? Muchas gracias!

Comment: Por favor, todos los mensajes de error y el código relevante han de ir en formato texto y no en imagen. Haz clic en [edit] y sustituye las imágenes por texto. Saludos

Comment: Intenta borrando el archivo package-lock.json y tratando nuevamente

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer es un [problema reciente](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11759) de `create-react-app` en su última [versión 5.0.0](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v5.0.0). Para parchear el conflicto con la configuración de `eslint` se recomienda:

1. Remover la configuración relacionada con `eslintConfig` del `package.json`.
2. Eliminar la carpeta de `node_modules`.
3. Instalar todas las dependencias nuevamente con `npm install`.

Espero eso solucione tu problema, al menos mientras solucionan el bug. Puedes seguir la discusión del problema [acá](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11759).